# Dock doesn't start after restarting from Bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, windows, dock

Whenever I am on my Bootcamp installation in Windows and restart to boot back into macOS the dock is no longer there. I can fix this by restarting in macOS. Is there any fix for this? Or does anybody know the reason for this behaviour.

- macOS Sierra Version 10.12.5
- Windows 7 in Bootcamp
- iMac (27-inch, Late 2012)
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680MX 2048 MB

Comment: Try option-command-D to show the dock again without rebooting

Comment: @paper1111: Thank you. I didn't know about this command. This works as a temporal fix, but I am still interested in the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried trashing the Dock plist? Maybe a corrupted file.

```
sudo rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
```

Run that in terminal it will remove the file and a new one will generate on next log in. Only downside to trying is it will reset your dock so you will have to put yours apps back to it any other setting you may have changed on it.